# Change WordPress RSS link with filter?

Tags: filters, hooks, rss

In my theme i use `add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );` to enable the rss links.

But i want to create an option to use Feedburner for the main rss feed, my problem is that i don't know how i can hook in and change the default rss link?

Comment: I usually use a simple plugin to redirect or do it in .htaccess to the same effect. Is that not acceptable?

Comment: Have you tried the Feedburner plugin?

Comment: I guess it is acceptable to use .htaccess, but it makes it harder for someone with less knowledge to do it if they use my theme.
I will check out the plugins :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you are doing. IMO, I don't include feedburner options within a theme. I leave that up to the end user. Is this still valid? http://justintadlock.com/archives/2008/12/15/how-to-change-your-feed-links-without-using-htaccess

Comment: I see your point, but i think it's nice to have the opportunity to easily add feedburner. But i want it to be optional. I will check your link :)

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the `template_redirect` hook and redirect any request to the WordPress feed to a URL that you define.

The most important thing to consider is the case when users are attempting to access the feed itself. In that case, you'd obviously not want to do any redirection.

Here's how you can do that:

```
function example_redirect_feeds() {

    // We only want to redirect if we're accessing the feed.
    if(is_feed()) {

        // Define the URL's to which we'll redirect...
        $feed_url = 'YOUR_FEED_REDIRECT_URL';
        $comment_feed_url = 'YOUR_COMMENT_FEED_REDIRECT_URL';

        global $feed, $withcomments;

        // If the user is requesting to access the comment feed, redirect...
        if($feed == 'comments-rss2' || $withcomments) {

            header("Location: " . $comment_feed_url);
            die();

        // ...otherwise, go ahead and redirect to the feeds you defined above.
        } else {

            // We need to capture all different feed types
            switch($feed) {

                case 'feed':
                case 'rdf':
                case 'rss':
                case 'rss2':
                case 'atom':

                    header("Location: " . $feed_url);
                    die();

                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            } // end switch/case

        } // end if/else

    } // end if

} // end example_redirect_feeds
add_action('template_redirect', 'example_redirect_feeds');
```

If you're planning to redirect feeds for comment streams, too then you'll need to add that to this function, as well.

Note that I'm unsure if using [`die`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) is the best practice here - it gets the job done, but "feels" a bit weak (though it *is* better than [`wp_die`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die) since that function is designed to actually return an error message - not just halt execution).

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation. I will try your solution :)